# Want to write unique filenames and paths to text file, duplicate names will have different extensions

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I am trying to write out the filepath for files with specific file extensions to a text file. There are some files that have different extensions but the same file name, and I am assuming these are duplicates and only want to retain one entry. Here is what I have for code - it is not writing anything out to the file. What am I missing?

```
import os
path = r'S:\Photogr\ASC'
file_ext_lst = ['.2dm','.2de','.3dm','.3de','.dgn']
txtfile = r'D:\test\microstation_filenames_paths.txt'


for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
      for filename in filenames:
              fullPath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
              name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
              if filename[-4:] in file_ext_lst:
                      with open(txtfile,'r+') as f:
                              for line in f:
                                      if name not in line:
                                              f.write(fullPath +'\n')
                      f.close()
```

Comment: you're reading and writing to the same file, in the same read/write position. You should `file.seek` as necessary, or do read/write separately

Comment: I see, I will try to use file.seek

Comment: You **can** - it's just hard. You need to keep track of the read/write position carefully not to overwrite existing text. When you `write` on the middle of the file, the contents after the write aren't "shifted over". It's similar to the operation of a text editor in "insert mode"

Comment: I am having trouble getting seek to work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code writes duplicate file names and paths to a text file.

```
import os
# path = r'S:\Photogr\ASC'
path = 'temp'
file_ext_lst = ['.2dm','.2de','.3dm','.3de','.dgn']
txtfile = r'D:\test\microstation_filenames_paths.txt'


found = dict()
for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        fullPath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        name,ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        if ext not in file_ext_lst:
            continue
        if name not in found:
            found[name] = fullPath

with open('unique.txt', 'w') as outf:
    print >>outf, 'Unique files:'
    for name,path in found.iteritems():
        print >>outf, '{:<10} {}'.format(name,path)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, what is this line doing? print >>outf, '{:<10} {}'.format(name,path) I want to modify it so that I only get the path as I'm feeding this into another program - nevemrind i see!

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I haven't tried creating some sample files and testing the code - if my first two suggestions do not help, I can try and look further!

You can remove `f.close()` after `with open()`, Python does that automatically for you.

You can also simplify the `with open()` block to:

```
with open(txtfile,'r+') as f:
    if name not in f.read():
        f.write(fullPath +'\n')
```

On another note: Opening and writing to your text file could happen a lot, which would be very slow - I would suggest storing your candidates in an array first and writing that to the text file only after the `os.walk()` part.

Comment: I get an error when I try to run this; Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Programming\Python\scripts\test.py", line 24, in <module>
    f.write(fullPath +'\n')
IOError: [Errno 0] Error